# How can I wrap each row of a HTML list field view in an a-tag

Tags: views, 9

I'm wondering how I can wrap an `<a>` tag around the `<li>`s rendered by the HTML list in Views.

Unfortunately I only find the option to wrap each field in a custom tag, but not the entire row. Can someone point me to the direction?

[image]
How can I do the above for the row of fields, not the field itself.

Edit: I also tried this.

[image]

But it doesn't wrap the fields around the a-tag.

Comment: I think it's not valid HTML to wrap `<li>` with `<a>`. You should wrap what's inside each `<li>` instead.

Comment: @leymannx that's fine too, but how can I wrap all fields in one a tag. It doesn't seem to work. Have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: @leymannx okay I understood it wasn't working. The title itself was a link also which was buggy to have a link in a link.